# Want to rotate 3d image of min3d library on touch event

Tags: android, 3d, image-rotation, min3d

I got the sample `min3d` `library` code and sample from google.com.

It is working perfect and even working with the changed image.

Now I want to rotate the `.obj` file with touch event like rotating the car on finger touch.
As it is using the animation object in `gl.rotation` method which is little difficult to understand.
I have no idea about it how to do so please provide me solution..

Comment: Have you found the solution yet ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add touch events as following

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
  //Your code goes here
  return true;
}
```

If you are not sure about how to rotate on touch events you can follow this link https://code.google.com/p/min3d/issues/detail?id=70